# Resizable images require a minimum deployment target of iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode5

In Xcode 5 when image is Sliced its giving Warning as ***Asset Catalog warning : Resizable images require a minimum deployment target of iOS 7*** ?

The Project deployment target is iOS 6.

Is this Slicing available only for iOS 7 ? If Yes how to do it for iOS 6 also .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it for iOS 6 you need to use the resizable image APIs.

Something like...

```
UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageWithAStretchyInside"];
UIImage *resizableImage = [normalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5)];
```

The `normalImage` will not resize properly. The `resizableImage` will.

The order of the edge insets is `top, left, bottom, right`.